# Sending new data from Java program to web browsers

Tags: java, javascript

I want to code a java program which must be able to communicate with web browsers (the clients). Sending data / answering requests is not a problem but I also want to send new data to the clients (so that they see it in their browsers without reloading the page).

What ways are there to accomplish that?
Is there any way to listen for new data (with JavaScript)?

Comment: With jQuery, JavaScript, or I personally suggest AJAX, because it's really helpful.

Comment: I used AJAX some times already, but only for requesting data from another php script. 
The point is, I dont want to manually send a AJAX request everytime to the server but rather do something when new data comes from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think what you are talking about is server push.
ie server will send data to client without polling from client.

There are various ways to do this one of the best way is through websockets.

you can use many java server available for websockets and have connect client for asynchronous push. while at client normal javascript will be able to receive the message.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Do you have any idea how exactly I can receive the message in javascript? Never did anything like that before..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications
Just look into example section.

Comment: That looks nice, thanks.
Seems to be pretty easy^^

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is called **Reverse Ajax**: Sending data from the server to a JavaScript-Enabled client (as opposed to a Regular Ajax, when the Client is the one that starts the communication). There 's [a nice article on DeveloperWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-reverseajax1/) that can introduce you into the subject.

There are several ways to accomplish Reverse Ajax, and them imply some customization in both Client Side components (i.e JavaScript) and the Server Components (Java in your particular case). As WebServer says, WebSockets is one alternative -although [is not supported by all browsers yet](http://caniuse.com/websockets)- but another viable solution is using [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29). If you're using Tomcat, [this link](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/WhatIsComet) might help you.